# How to send Image ( Photo parameter) to javascript adapter from a cordova app using Post Method

Tags: javascript, android, ios, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am facing an issue with sending image to javascript adapter from Cordova App using WLResourceRequest with WLResourceRequest.GET

**Error:**

> Response Error :
>       {"status":414,"statusText":"Request URI too 
>       long","responseText":"Request URI is too long","responseHeaders": 
>       {"cache-control":"no-cache,no-store","content-length":"23","content- 
>       type":"text/html","expires":"now","pragma":"no- 
>       cache"},"errorMsg":"Request URI too long","errorCode":"414"}

**Cordova App Source Code:**

```
 var invocationData = {
"LOCALE":locale,
"CHANNEL":channel,
"CLIENT_OS":os,
"TYPE":type,
"ISSUE_TYPE":issueType,
"LOCATION":loc,
"CONTRACT_ACC_NO":accNo,
"PHOTOS":photo
 };


 var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
 "/adapters/Report/makeReport",WLResourceRequest.GET);
resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", [invocationData]);
resourceRequest.send().then((response) => {
this.content = response.responseJSON;
deferred.resolve(this.content);
},
function(error){
deferred.reject(error);
}
 );
```

**Java Script Adapter Source Code:**

```
function invokeBackend(args, proc){
var path = "SEB-Middleware/api/" + proc;
var input = {
method : 'post',
returnedContentType : 'json',
path : path,
body : {
contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
content: JSON.stringify(args)
}
};
var response = MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
return response ;
}
```

Above code working successful response without passing image(PHOTOS) parameter,

**Also tried below code using POST method :**

```
 var formParams = {"params": [invocationData]};
 var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest( 
 "/adapters/Report/makeReport",WLResourceRequest.POST; 
 resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams).then(
    function(response) {
      console.log('return result');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      // success flow
    },
    function(error) {
      // fail flow
      console.log('return error');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  );
```

> Response error: "Error: Invalid invocation of method 
>        WLResourceRequest.sendFormParameters; Form value must be a simple 
>        type.

**Another Method:**

```
 var formParams = {"params": [JSON.stringify(invocationData)]};
 var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/Report/makeReport",WLResourceRequest.POST);
 resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams).then((response) => 
 {
 this.content = response.responseJSON;

 deferred.resolve(this.content);
  },
 function(error){
 deferred.reject(error);
 }
 );

Response error: "Error: Invalid invocation of method 
WLResourceRequest.sendFormParameters; Form value must be a simple 
type.
```

Please can you advise for how to pass the image(PHOTOS) parameter from cordova app to javascript adapter using WLResourceRequest with POST ?

Comment: What is the data type of your "photo" variable? WLResourceRequest needs to be a simple type. Can you convert it into a base64 string and try again?

Comment: my photo is array of base64 Image. I need to send at max 3 images to the server.When i use get method the error 414 occur, so i need to use post method but the problem is the json

Comment: The parameter needs to be a json or a string. The problem might be due to the photo being sent as an array. Please change the array into a json and make the adapter call.
Or alternatively send the 3 images as 3 parameters and change the adapter accordingly to accept 3 parameters.

Comment: i change the json into string and try to send the json data without photo, it still show the same error and from the adapter as you can see, throught GET and sendQueryParameter method it pass to "arg" variable, but using sendFormParameter and POST it did not pass any value to "arg" in the adapter side, is there any specific way to retrieve the parameter send by sendFormParameter at Javascript adapter. Please check my adapter code thanks

Comment: Can you use a java adapter and try instead? In case of java adapter, it would accept any parameter as an Object data.